# Confused about auto property IL accessing two arguments rather than one

Tags: .net, .net-4.5, il, ildasm

Given the following auto property:

`public string Name { get; set; }`

I analysed it's IL using ILDASM and was curious about the result:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname instance void 
        set_Name(string 'value') cil managed
{
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       8 (0x8)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldarg.1
  IL_0002:  stfld      string Strings.Person::'<Name>k__BackingField'
  IL_0007:  ret
} // end of method Person::set_Name
```

I can see that the method takes in a parameter named `value`, which corresponds to the call `ldarg.0`. However, the call to `ldarg.1` caught me out as I cannot see a second parameter in the method signature.

Was hoping that someone could explain what's going on here please?

Comment: Don't know much about IL, but as it's an instance property, wouldn't it need a "this pointer", too?

Comment: An instance member always has an extra hidden argument.  It passes *this*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `ldarg.0` loads the hidden `this` parameter.
- `ldarg.1` loads `value`
- `stfld` assigns the value on top of the stack to a field in the object below it on the stack.